# Magento 2.3 Change product status to out-of-stock when qty is less than 'Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart'

Tags: magento2.3, plugin, inventory, override-block

I'm running Magento 2.3.5.

Some of my products have Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart set to greater than one.

For example, product A has Minimum Qty Allowed: 7.
Currently, the QTY of A is: 10.
Now a customer bought 7 of A and now QTY become: 3.
At this moment the status of this item is still In Stock, however, customers can't add it to the cart and the error will pop up saying the qty if greater than the stock.

This is very annoying and this affects the user experience.

If I want to write a plugin of override, which class should I start with?

Thank you!

Edit:
So I wanted to make the product 'out of stock' programmatically when qty is less than the 'Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart'. I tried to set the out of stock threshold to 6 to achieve this, but then it only allows people to buy 4 even though I have 10.  I am not sure which block(s) controls this?

Comment: For which things you want to write plugin?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya So I wanted to make the product 'out of stock' programmatically when qty is less than the 'Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart'. I tried to set the out of stock threshold to 6 to achieve this, but then it only allows people to buy 4 even though I have 10. I am not sure which block(s) controls this.